# Cherrypy Session Release KeyError

Tags: python, cherrypy

I've written a python web-based asset management system to manage the production of a short cg animation. I'm using Python2.7, SQLAlchemy with SQLite, and CherryPy.

It's currently being used in production and for the most part it's working fine. The system keeps production data on a central server and allows users to 'check out' assets to their local machine. It does this by running a small python service on the client machine, which the server communicates with over XMLRPC. The issue I'm having arises when users are checking assets in or out or publishing assets; all of which are requests that can take minutes to complete because of large files, although most of the time they take 10s of seconds.

The problem is that CherryPy raises a KeyError when it tries to release a session at the end of the request. Here's the traceback:

```
[29/Apr/2013:15:39:02]  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/i7858384/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 102, in run
    hook()
  File "/home/i7858384/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 62, in __call__
    return self.callback(**self.kwargs)
  File "/home/i7858384/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py", line 698, in save
    cherrypy.session.save()
  File "/home/i7858384/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py", line 230, in save
    self.release_lock()
  File "/home/i7858384/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py", line 374, in release_lock
    self.locks[self.id].release()
KeyError: u'6f23f62a29d3db4ad18c89165d23c1b7170570b8'

[29/Apr/2013:15:39:02] HTTP 
Request Headers:
  Content-Length: 2698301
  HOST: 172.16.76.31:8080
  Remote-Addr: 172.16.76.164
  ACCEPT: */*
  USER-AGENT: python-requests/0.14.2 CPython/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  ACCEPT-ENCODING: gzip, deflate, compress
[29/Apr/2013:15:39:02] HTTP Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/i7858384/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 660, in respond
    self.hooks.run('before_finalize')
  File "/home/i7858384/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 112, in run
    raise exc
KeyError: u'6f23f62a29d3db4ad18c89165d23c1b7170570b8'
```

For example, when the user checks an asset out, their shown a loading bar through a bootstrap modal. If this session error occurs, it obviously will hang indefinitely. But when the user reloads the page, they see that the asset has checked out and everything processed correctly. So I'm assuming that this error occurs right at the end of the request, after everything has been processed correctly.

Comment: Are you using with `-O` `python -O` or `python -OO`, or using the method of the session directly, like `cherrypy.session.save()`?, the the RamSession, right?

Comment: Possibly related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12703347/372643). I realise this question was asked a long time ago, but were you running this application in a single process, or were you using a front-end (e.g. Apache with `mod_python`, WSGI, FastCGI, ...) which could have spawned multiple processes?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably being affected by a race condition in CherryPy's `RamSession` implementation, as described in [this pull request](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/pull-request/50/fix-race-condition-in-session-clean-up/diff).

Although the patch might not be automatically applicable depending on the version of CherryPy you were using, this part of the code doesn't seem to have changed for a while, so you might be able to patch it manually.